# What happens to alkyd enamel paint below 5 degrees C?

Tags: paint, alkyd, weather

I'm impatient to paint a fiberglass boat I'm restoring and I'm using an alkyd enamel paint which states it's okay down to 5 degrees C.

Although daytime temperature is 10 degrees C and more, night time lows are down towards freezing point.

Will the cold just increase the drying time, or do you think it could actually damage the paint, causing it to fail?

Comment: Your best bet is calling the mfg, I have seen some strange things when paint was used outside it’s published range. Being impatient could run into stripping it and having to redo it. so probably it would be best to wait for warmer weather.

Comment: @EdBeal I think you're right. I had trouble enough doing the fiberglass repairs using epoxy. Chicken lamp in a crate and blankets worked great as the repairs were small in area. But painting the whole boat... keeping an eye on the weather forecast!